# Displaying Category and Sub Category names in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, displayobject

I want to display exact subcategory and category names in my header. I tried everything and Still couldn't able to find a solution yet. Im in subcategory controller when I clicket a subcategory name and In category controller when I clicker a category name. According to that my header must display corresponding categories and subcategories. This is my subcategory controller show action.

```
def show
  @subcategories = Subcategory.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @products = @subcategories.products.where(approved: true)
  @subcategories= Subcategory.all
  @categories= Category.all
  @products = Product.order(:name).page params[:page]
end
```

This is my category controller show action

```
def show
  @categories = Category.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @products = @categories.products.where(approved: true)
  @categories= Category.all
  @subcategories= Subcategory.all
end
```

and this is my show.html.erb file the way I tried to display categories and sub categories.

```
<li><a href="#" title=""><%= @categories.name%></a></li>
<li><a href="#" title=""><%= @subcategories.name %></a></li>
```

This is my products.rb corresponding snippet

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :subcategory
```

currently displaying as

Category > Subcategory when I clicked a subcategory. Can you suggest a way to do that.

PS: this is for a ebay like application.

Comment: Why are you doing things like assigning the value of `@products = ` twice in a row? It makes no sense.

Comment: Oh i think its a big mistake.. Im trying to display categories.. doing everything.. thanks for noticing it. PS: Im a beginner.

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues. Also I'm not clear on what you have that actually works. Can you post an image of what the view produced actually looks like? And then maybe a better description of what you WANT  it to look like?

Comment: Thank you for your help I solved my question. I removed duplication.

Comment: The issue was in show actions and I fixed it. I used "@subcategory" and "@category" instead of "@subcategories" and "@categories", and "@categories" - Category.all and "@subcategories = Subcategory.all" instead of the codes before.(for corresponding places). And I have called those incorrectly. I called "@subcategory.category.name" for display the name of the category and "@subcategory.name" to display the name of subcategory in subcategory show file. And I used "@category.name" to display the category in category show file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do here, but I think I understand the basic structure of what you're trying to build: you click a category and you display all subcategories for that category, and when you click a subcategory you get all the products that are in that subcategory.

If this is true, it can be accomplished like this:

Categories Controller:

```
def index # Give the view all categories to list
  @categories = Category.order("created_at DESC")
end

 def show
   @category = Category.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Categories View:

```
#Links to each category
<li><%=link_to(@category.name, category_path)%></li>
```

Subcategories Controller:

```
# This will be identical to the products controller snippet,
# but obviously change subcategory to product

def index # Give the view subcategories of the category to list
  @subcategories = Subcategory.order("created_at DESC")
end

 def show # This path will display a single subcategory
   @subcategory = Subcategory.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Subcategory View:

```
<h3><%= @subcategory.name %></h3> #Display the subcategory name as title
<% @subcategory.products.each do |product| %> # Access each product related to the subcategory
   <li><%=link_to(product.title, post_path(product))%></li> # Create a link, the name of the product, to the individual product
   <li><%= product.description %></li> # Description or whatever you put here.
<% end %>
```

If you're doing what I think you are, this is probably what you're looking for. Here, I'm assuming that each subcategory belongs to one category, which might not be how you planned it - which is fine, but that's just generally how sites are set up. If you want multiple category and subcategory associations, you may be thinking of tags instead, and might want to look rethink your structure.

Either way, you're giving the controller (in your original post) too much information. If you have the subcategory or category id you can find the products associated with it via a `@category = Category.find(params[:id])` etc. You can also use that product to display all categories/subs with a `where`. Again, I would suggest a simple linear association between category/sub/product, since this makes things far easier and more intuitive for you, and allows you to do what I did with subcategories and products above ie: `subcategory.products.each`.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the help and this helped me a lot. Now subcategories are displayed but Displaying category is not working. Ill follow that answer, and Thank you again. !

Comment: Glad to hear it! Obviously I can't tell what your issue with categories is without seeing the code, but if I had to guess, I'd say its your associations. If you're planning on doing something similar to what I wrote above, you might be missing the "has many through" association to link categories to products. If you're setting up products as belonging to both cats and subcats, the issue might be resolved by associating products with both as a polymorphic association, but that's beyond the scope of this small comment box. Good luck again! :)

Comment: My problem is solved. thank you for the help. The issue was in show actions and I fixed it. I used "@subcategory" and "@category" instead of "@subcategories" and "@categories", and "@categories" - Category.all and "@subcategories = Subcategory.all" instead of the codes before.(for corresponding places). And I have called those incorrectly. I called "@subcategory.category.name" for display the name of the category and "@subcategory.name" to display the name of subcategory in subcategory show file. And I used "@category.name" to display the category in category show file.